# Efficiency of form based authentication against LDAP in Java apps

Tags: java, security, ldap, weblogic12c

I built a couple of apps in Java that run on Weblogic 12C with authentication from an OpenLDAP server. The OpenLDAP authenticator is defined in Weblogic security realm. Pages / URL's are secured by role-based authorization. The setup is similar to that given [here](https://www.developer.com/open-source/introduction-to-securing-web-applications-with-jboss-and-ldap/).

However, is such a setup efficient? At login, a call would be sent to the LDAP server to authenticate users, of course. But if I use `if(request.isUserInRole("Member_admin")){` extensively within JSP pages and servlets, would a call be sent each time, or are the results cached? If each triggers a call, that would slow things down tremendously when the app is under load.

Comment: Is it efficient? Have you measured it?

Comment: No, as I am not conversant with alternate methods to be able to compare.